# Twilio - HTTP Authentication for Call Recordings and MMS Media - How to access the media with HTTP authentication?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I have received an email from Twilio saying they will be enforcing HTTP Authentication for Call Recordings and MMS Media.

I have coupled applications where we store the mms media url and voice call recording urls to access from Twilio.

What is the change to be done when HTTP authentication is enforced? I am using Twilio PHP client SDK for may application.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

currently all recordings and media stored on Twilio's side is under public URL's that can be accessed by anyone. The URL's are randomly generated and hence it's unlikely for malicious actors to guess these but none the less they are open to the internet for convenience.

From July, you will be required to authenticate when accessing these resources using the account's SID + auth token or an API key/password combination. Therefore you will need to update any code which is accessing these resources to authenticate itself appropriately. If you are using an SDK tied to an account then the auth on creation of this client will apply to these media requests.

You can read about media protection [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183748-Prevent-Unauthorized-Access-to-Your-Media-with-HTTP-Basic-Auth).

Comment: Thanks. How do we authenticate? Is there any code samples?

Comment: If you are using the SDK then you've already authed since you provide the account SID/auth token OR API key/secret when generating a client.

If you are sending HTTP requests yourself then you can use HTTP basic authentication with the above combinations to validate your requests. The [media messaging docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/rest/media) show an example of this but if you are familiar with Basic then it should flow fairly easily

Comment: In our application, when we receive an incoming mms message, we get the mediaurl of the image. This url is stored in the database. We will display the image received in the front end UI using the media url stored. Will it work still?

Comment: Understood, this will no longer work directly. Instead when you need to display this image then you will need to authenticate against this URL, retrieve the media URL which is returned and use this. This will be valid for 4 hours at which you will need to authenticate once more.

Comment: The authentication for this image will likely need to be done server-side to avoid exposing your account keys but you can then use this media URL on the client side